# Ограниченное время жизни контейнеров Servlets API

Tags: java, servlet

Как регулируется время жизни `HttpRequest`, `HttpSession`, `ServletContext`, `HttpResponce` программно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

см. на `HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval()`

Comment: я имел ввиду, на уровне кода. Внутри API

Comment: Дык, я вроде как код и дал или я чего-то не догоняю? [HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval(int))

Comment: мне нужен самый низкий уровень абстракции Java.  Функция setMaxInactiveInterval() сама содержит внутри себя Java код

Comment: @voipp как вы видимо уже усмотрели из документации `HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval()` - это метод интерфейса, то есть конкретная его реализация зависит от конкретного сервера (или в данном контексте от сервлет контейнера). Для контейнера Catalina из Tomcat'а [исходники здесь](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/catalina/session/StandardSession.java.html)

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно было!